# Android 10 MediaStore update image RecoverableSecurityException

Tags: android, mediastore, android-10.0, scoped-storage

I'm in the process of updating an Android app to scoped storage and the problem I'm facing now is that on my app users can select a set of images to be processed automatically (and they can choose to overwrite the original image).

The problem is, when I'm trying to overwrite the original image from its Uri, Android throws a `RecoverableSecurityException`, which displays a dialog to the user asking consent to modify that photo.

What I want to know is if it's possible to instead show a permission dialog but for the whole set of, for example, 10 images at once, instead of having to show a dialog for each one.

I tried using the `applyBatch` method of `ContentResolver` (the code below simulates the issue), but the consent dialog only shows for the first updated image.

```
val values = ContentValues().apply {
                put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_MODIFIED, System.currentTimeMillis())
            }
            val ops = arrayListOf<ContentProviderOperation>()
            for (image in galleryImages) {
                ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(image.uri)
                        .withValues(values)
                        .build())
            }
            context.contentResolver.applyBatch(MediaStore.AUTHORITY, ops)
```

Any ideas on this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately in Android Q is not possible. But, in the Android Summit 2019 the team stated that bulk edit and delete will be possible in the next Android release, so supposedly in the future version 'R'.

See the next video, starting at minute 18:50, where they talk briefly about it:

https://youtu.be/UnJ3amzJM94

The only solution in Android Q is to get SAF rights over the directory you want to operate with and use the DocuentFile API instead of the MediaStore.

Answer (score 0):

As an addition, for android 11 I found a way to solve it without additional permission request by catching RecoverableSecurityException and throw my own exception:

```
try {
    //try to modify
} catch (RecoverableSecurityException e) {
    List<Uri> uris = //map photo list to uri
    PendingIntent pIntent = MediaStore.createWriteRequest(contentResolver, uris);
    throw new RecoverableSecurityExceptionExt(pIntent);
}


public class RecoverableSecurityExceptionExt extends SecurityException {

    private final PendingIntent pIntent;

    public RecoverableSecurityExceptionExt(PendingIntent pIntent) {
        this.pIntent = pIntent;
    }

    public PendingIntent getPIntent() {
        return pIntent;
    }
}
```

Then catch second exception, get IntentSender from PendingIntent and process it like regular RecoverableSecurityException with startIntentSenderForResult(...) and so on